# How can I convert a shapefile from AGD66 to GDA94 from a script, using open source libraries

Tags: bash, gis, geography, coordinate-systems, shapefile

How can I convert a shapefile from AGD66 to GDA94 programmatically, using open source libraries?  I don't want to use `arcgisscripting` because I don't have a licence.

This needs to be automatable.  A bash or python script would be acceptable.

This is a little more complicated than a normal reprojection, because a different ellipsoid is used between these coordinate reference systems, and thus a distortion grid needs to be used.

Comment: If you wanted to know about how to *write* the software, it would be topical here; if you want to *use* existing software, it probably belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer own question, but here goes for posterity.  Using the [instructions here](http://opaqueoverlay.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/reprojecting-from-agd66-to-gda94/), first download the distortion grid:

```
wget http://www.icsm.gov.au/icsm/gda/gdatm/national66.zip
unzip national66.zip
mkdir -p ~/bin
mv "A66 National (13.09.01).gsb" ~/bin/a66_national.gsb
rm national66.zip
```

Then use ogr2ogr to reproject:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=aust_SA +nadgrids=~/bin/a66_national.gsb +wktext" -t_srs EPSG:4283 outputgda94.shp inputagd66.shp
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the OpenSource GDAL libraries.

To convert coordinates on their own us the GGAL transform utility: 
http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html

To convert a whole shapefile use:
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

There is a command line example for a shapefile at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Sorry read too quickly, and missed it was for whole shapefiles. Added the correct utility link - but I saw that you'd already found it. 
There are also Python bindings for GDAL if you need to use this as part of a longer process.

Comment: It was the business with gridshift files that was killing me in the end